# Which is best way to detect external led flashing with ESP8266 keeping circuit power consumption very low?

Tags: photodiode, esp8266, light-sensor, photoresistor

I have an external led (color is red) which flash with variable frequency. I need to monitor those flashes, calculating how many time led flash in a minute and log them.

I made a first try with an Arduino + photoresistor + LM358 as comparator (to get ON/OFF signal from photoresistor) and it works.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvgcoz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I use them because I have those components available to make a test, but now I need to create a very small circuit with very low power consumption and wireless connection.

**Specs:**

- microcontroller: ESP8266-01
- VDD: 3.3V (coin battery)
- led frequency up to (about) 5Hz

What about the light sensor circuit? What is the best way to simplify it and keep consumption very low?

**NOTE: I cannot open/modify the device I need to monitor. The only way to monitor its activity is through led activity**

Comment: This smells soooo much like an XY problem, what are you really trying to solve? I have never seen an application where monitoring a blinking LED was the proper solution.

Comment: What about replacing the LED by an optocoupler, as it includes a LED inside?

Comment: I have an electricity meter which flashes an LED once per consumption of somewhere around (I'd guess) 10k Joules. Counting the flashes is intended to be a non-contact way of reading the electricity consumption, there's even a recess around the LED areas designed to hold a companion opto detector. I'll get around to it some time! How long are the flashes? A good way to save power is to sleep most of the time. Is there time to power up the light detector, have it stabilise, go to sleep again for 90% of the time, all within the duration of one flash? You can't open a meter to mess with the LED.

Comment: It's similar to what Neil_UK says: 
**I cannot disassembly, modify, etc the device*** I need to monitor. The only way is to monitor its activity through reading led activity.
Led frequency is not very high, up to about 5Hz ().

Comment: Led frequency is about 5Hz, but what about the duty cycle? I mean, is it on during 10ms and off during 200ms, or is it 50%-50%?

Comment: Frequency is not fixed. It is variable: according with my measure with Arduini circuit, frequency never exceed 5Hz, but it can be lower ( < 0.5Hz too). I never analyze the duty cycle because I though it does make no sense in this context.

Comment: Keep the light detection circuit active until light is detected. Once, light is off, STEP1: go to sleep for MINIMUM_NO_LED_DURATION. STEP 2 start scanning for LED for less than MINIMUM_LED_ON_DURATION duration. goto step 1.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, ever worked in the kWh-meter business? ;)  (lots of blinking LED monitoring apparatus there)

Comment: @PkP: those I have worked with had an IR LED that would constantly transmit data

Comment: @Noisemaker duty cycle is relevant, since, if you use a phototransistor and it is conducting most of the time (because LED is on), it means the pullup will waste power most of the time (R1 in pjc50's schematic). This will probably be your main drain, besides the ESP8266 itself.

Comment: @Noisemaker so, if you want to reduce this power waste, you could, for exmple, connect the upper end of the pullup to a GPIO, so you don't activate the pullup permanently, but just when you check (regularily). Whether it's worth it (or completely overengineered) depends on your LED duty cycle.

Comment: With the arduino circuit I used interrupt on the pin where sensor has been attached to. So my idea was using the same approach with ESP8266 (should be possible).

So, the sleep state will be next step, by now I need to know the best way to generate a LOW/HIGH signal when led is OFF/ON respectively. This will trigger the interrupt.

Using a high value pullup resistor should reduce power consumption enough?

Comment: Using a higher pullup will reduce power consumption, but you'll have slower response time. And if you set it too high, the leakage may become significant and the high level will be too low to be properly recognized. Now, whether it will be "enough" is a matter of compromise and it depends on lots of factors I'm not aware of (LED duty cycle, ESP8266 standby current, ESP8266 transmit current, transmit timings, expected lifetime, etc...).

Comment: I'm thinking about a photodiode: on inverse polarization it let current flow only when light is on, right? So no power wasted when LED is off.

Comment: I found a IR photodiode in my electronics component box and I tried: it works great detecting red led light, but it is too much sensitive on external IR sources (like others light in the environment around the circuit).

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with https://github.com/dkroeske/emon-server :

[image]

However, I'm using it with a Pi that's wired for power and Ethernet. I've never bothered to measure its power consumption, but if you use a CMOS 555 and get rid of the diagnostic LED it should be fairly low.

You're going to have serious problems running an ESP8266 off coin cells. The transmit power can be several hundred miliamps.

Comment: you're right! I didn't take care of transmission power (it send data every 10 minutes). Switching to a 3.7V Li-Ion battery with voltage regulator should work?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. I'm not familiar enough with the ESP's programming model to know how it handles sleep, but for best battery life it should be asleep and off the wifi as much as possible. If it's not very good at sleep it may be worth adding a tiny microcontroller just to do the counting and power control for the ESP.